# Trying to put all the values below and above the main diagonal equal to 0 in a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, line, rows

So my fuction to put all zeros except the main diagonal is a mess and its not doing the work.

The first function is going to subtract each entrance on a line of a matrix for (one of the main diagonal entrance * ( one of the main diagonal entrance * ( one of the main diagonal entrance / an entrance below or above the main entrance). (Sorry for my English)

```
def subtract_lines(m,r,x,y):
for i in range(r,r + 1):
    for j in range(0,m.shape[1]):
        m[i,j] = m[i,j] - (y * (x / y))
return m
```

The second function is supossed to give me a answer like this: numpy.array([[4.0,2.0,3.0],[3.0,4.0,3.0],[2.0,5.0,6.0]] = array([[ x., 0.,  0.],[ 0.,  x.,  0.],[0.,  0.,  x.]]) x = Random Number. (I hope i had this result in my code)

```
def all_zeros(m):
for i in range(0,m.shape[0]):
    for j in range(0,m.shape[1]):
            for l in range(0,m.shape[0]):
                for c in range(0,m.shape[1]):
                    if i == j and l != i:
                        subtract_lines(m,l,m[l,j],m[i,j])
return m
```

If someone can understand what I´m saying and can help me, I would be extremely grateful!

Comment: Is `x` a completely random number? What is it supposed to equal?

Answer (score 0):

(I'm not entirely certain I'm interpreting your question correctly, but I don't have enough reputation to clarify as a comment so this is my best attempt at an answer.)

Numpy has some helper functions that seem like they would save you a lot of work: if `m` is a matrix with n rows and n columns, `m.diagonal()` is a matrix with 1 row and n columns representing the diagonal entries of your matrix in order. The function `numpy.fill_diagonal(m, x)` will fill the diagonal cells of your matrix with the value `x` (or the values of x in order, if x is a list, matrix, or similar data type containing the values you want to place in the diagonal).

I am not clear about the exact. purpose of `subtract_lines`, and it would help me to understand if you gave an example input and the desired output like you did with the other function.

Comment: Basically I´m trying to invert a matrix using the Jordan-Guass Method. What I´m doing is trying to put all values under the main diagonal equal to zero, and i cant do that like the method...

Comment: The purpose of subtract lines is to eliminate te values of a row, for example: numpy.array([1,2],[3,4]) ----> output: [1,2],[0,-2] so you eliminate m[2,1]. This is the output that i want but subtract lines dont do that so.... i need help

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being late here. I'm just going to answer the question in the title: "How to set all values above and below the diagonal to zero in a matrix."

Its quite simple:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        if i == j:
            # We are on a diagonal, do nothing
            continue
        else:
            arr[i,j] = 0
```

If you want to only set the "upper" triangle to zero, you would use this instead:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        if i > j:
            # We are above the diagonal
            arr[i,j] = 0
        else:
            continue
```

And lastly, if you only want to set the lower diagonal to zero:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])

for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        if i < j:
            # We are below the diagonal
            arr[i,j] = 0
        else:
            continue
```